# Django 1.5 and new User model : what about third party apps?

Tags: django, django-models

I am making some tests on a development site, currently using **Django 1.4**.
Most Django users are aware that Django 1.5 brings more flexibility in User models.

The project I'm working on uses monkey-patching on the `auth.User` model, and it works well. This adds useful methods I use everytime.

I have not added any database field on the User model for the sake of compatibility, my code only involves this:

```
User.__bases__ += (UserPlus,)
User.__unicode__ = UserPlus.__unicode__
UserPlusManager().contribute_to_class(User, 'objects')
```

with `UserPlusManager` being a subclass of `UserManager`.

Now, imagine I want to switch to the new user model. I already have many apps in `INSTALLED_APPS`, some of them are on unmaintained repos and have models with fields tied to auth.User.
I don't see a ny obvious strategy for this kind of configuration.

So, is it really advisable to upgrade to **Django 1.5** with this in mind ? If so, what steps should I take ?

Comment: imo, monkey-patching auth.User is an extremely easy way to paint yourself into a corner when it comes to forwards compatibility. If you want to go to 1.5, you're most likely going to be refacoring out your patches.

Comment: Actually, I have monkey patched the auth.User model, but have not added any database field for compatibility. I have changed some methods and replaced the default manager with a compatible one. I'm going to augment my first post with this piece of information.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a "good" answer to your question, as it's completely subjective based on whatever code leverages your monkey-patched User.

Comment: I can always refactor my current code, but the true question is how can I deal with existing third party apps everywhere on Github and Bitbucket ? (e.g. django-activity-stream) I think they would break with the new model.

Comment: If Django changes their constructs, those apps have to respond. If that app isn't 1.5 compatible, that pretty much answers your question for you.

Comment: That's what I thought, thank you. Could you make it a full answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a construct in Django changes, any third-party apps that leverage that construct would have to react accordingly. If your project is dependent on third-party apps that aren't 1.5 compatible, you should wait to upgrade your project until they are.